# Rewrite rule to hide folder, doesn't work right without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

i have a strange apache mod_rewrite problem. I need to hide a sub-directory from the user, but redirect every request to that sub-directory. I found several quite similar issues on stackoverflow, but nothing really fits, so i decided to post a new question.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ foo/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The document-root only contains the following folder/files:

```
/foo/bar/index.html
```

I would now expect that example.com/bar and example.com/bar/ would just show me the contents of index.html.

Instead example.com/bar/ show me the content as expected but example.com/bar redirects me with a 301 to example.com/bar/foo/ an then shows the contents. I really don't get why there is a 301 redirect in this case.

When i put something this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[^.]*/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[^.]*\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[^.]*\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [QSA,L]
```

on top of that rule it seems to work, but that would require me to list every used file extension...

Is there any other way i can omit the redirect, the folder "bar" should never be seen by an outside user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never...

Got it working with a simple RewriteRule which append a / to every url that doesn't have on.

```
# only directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# exclude there directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded-dirs
# exclude these extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.excluded-extension$
# exclude request that already have a /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `^(.*)/?$` would make the trailing slash optional FYI

Answer (score 0):

1st rewrite rule is redirect from /foo/(.*) to ($1) and second - from (.*) to $1.

*just idea, this has not been tested.*