# Remove file extension and file name

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I used this code to remove the .php file extension on my website

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

This worked to change my url from example.com/contact/contact.php to example.com/contact/contact but I would like the url to not have the file name after the folder that it is in. I would like it to look like example.com/contact/ Any thoughts?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334289/rewrite-rule-to-hide-folder-doesnt-work-right-without-trailing-slash#answer-5750339

Comment: What if folder `/contact/` also have another php file like `main.php`, what you be URL for that file?

Comment: I think you should move your files to your website root.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is by naming the file index.php when navigating to the folder, the index.php file wil be served. 
So when navigating to /contact /contact/index.php will be displayed.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index